# Microsoft SQL Server: Need to Compare Two Sets of Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have two queries that each give me list of orders and the number of line items on each order.  We are migrating systems, and one is from the source, and the other from the target.  I need to do some validation between them.

I want to compare them so that my result is a list of orders where the number of lines do not match.  If an order should be in the target but isn't, it should also appear on the list.

I have been fighting with this for a full day and I cannot wrap my head around how to approach it.

Help would be appreciated!

Here are the two queries:

SOURCE QUERY

```
select s.oNum, count(s.oNum) 
  from SourceTbl s
    left join PK_Master pk
      on pk.Num = s.oNum
  where s.oNum not in (select ordernum from tmpSalesOrders)
  group by s.oNum
order by s.oNum
```

TARGET QUERY

```
select p.oNum, count(p.oNum) 
  from BridgeTbl p
    left join TargetTbl t 
      on p.ToNum = t.orderID
  group by p.oNum
order by p.oNum
```

SourceTable is a superset, and PK_Master and tmpSalesOrders are used to refine the orders that SHOULD be migrated.

The BridgeTbl has a field called SoNum that = s.oNum to link the source and target.

I need the source order number (s.oNum) in the result set.

Comment: Toss `EXCEPT` between those two queries and let 'er rip. That will tell you records that are outputted by your first query that aren't in your second query. You could also toss each select statement into a subquery and LEFT OUTER JOIN using `oNum` where your counts aren't equal.

Comment: EXCEPT worked perfect.  That's a new one for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Put your comment in the answer so I can mark it answered :D

Comment: I'm glad that did the trick. I have added as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toss `EXCEPT` between those two queries and let 'er rip. That will tell you records that are outputted by your first query that aren't in your second query.

```
select s.oNum, count(s.oNum) 
  from SourceTbl s
    left join PK_Master pk
      on pk.Num = s.oNum
  where s.oNum not in (select ordernum from tmpSalesOrders)
  group by s.oNum
order by s.oNum

EXCEPT

select p.oNum, count(p.oNum) 
  from BridgeTbl p
    left join TargetTbl t 
      on p.ToNum = t.orderID
  group by p.oNum
order by p.oNum
```

`EXCEPT` is a "Set Operator". In TSQL you can [`UNION`, `UNION ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`EXCEPT`, and `INTERSECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) sets.